# Entity Framework won't save complex object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco

I have basically  the following poco classes

```
public class AddressType 
{ 
public Guid AddressTypeId;
public string TypeName;
}

public class Address
{
...

public virtual Guid AddressTypeID { get; set; }
public virtual AddressType AddressType { get; set; }
}

public class Locale
{
public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

With the following in my context to create the database

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.AddressType)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey( p => p.AddressTypeID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete( false );

modelBuilder.Entity<AddressType>().HasKey(p => p.AddressTypeID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<AddressType>().Property(p => p.AddressTypeID)
           .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
modelBuilder.Entity<AddressType>().Property(p => p.TypeName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(32);
```

Now that all looks good to me.  Heres the problem.
I can create a Locale then add an address to it like this

```
...

    Locale locale = iRepostory.Locales.Where( p => p.LocaleID == new Guid("xxxx")).SingleOrDefault();
    Address address = new Address();
    address.AddressTypeID = "xxxxx";
    address.AddressType = iRepository.AddressTypes.Where( p => p.AddressTypeID == "xxxx").SingleOrDefault();
    iRepository.SaveLocale(locale);

That works fine. 

Now if I attempt to add an additional address it fails
Locale locale = iRepostory.Locales.Where( p => p.LocaleID == new Guid("xxxx")).SingleOrDefault();
    Address address = new Address();
    address.AddressTypeID = "xxxxx";
    address.AddressType = iRepository.AddressTypes.Where( p => p.AddressTypeID == "xxxx").SingleOrDefault();
locale.Adresses.Add(address);
    iRepository.SaveLocale(locale);

It seems the error from the EntityValidationErrors
is
EntityValidationErrors.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name is AddressType
EntityValidationErrors.Entry.State is Added
then for that EntityValidateError.ValidationErrors
ValidationError.Property = TypeName
```

Why can't i add additional addresses?
I know that the error is coming from the Address that is already added to the Locale because I created an address and set it's Locale_LocaleID directly in the database and then I get two sets of errors.
Why are the addresses that are already added causing this error?

Comment: What is the validation error `ErrorMessage`?